# Update modal with AJAX query and awaiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a basic jQuery function with AJAX. When a button is clicked, an AJAX call is made and upon success, the modal's HTML is set to the response.

The code works fine but the issue I'm coming across is that when the modal is launched a second time. It displays the HTML content of the previous AJAX call then changes immediately after 1-2. So it makes me think the show method is being called before the HTML has been entirely set to the response.

Current Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click',
        '.show-quickview',
        function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/Product/Index',
                data: {
                    slug: this.id,
                    type: this.name,
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#quickviewModal").html(response);                        
                    $('#quickviewModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });


});
```

I tried to put the show within the complete and I still get the same response.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click',
        '.show-quickview',
        function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/Product/Index',
                data: {
                    slug: this.id,
                    type: this.name,
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#quickviewModal").html(response);
                },
                complete: function(response) {
                    $('#quickviewModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });


});
```

May I ask how do I get quickviewModel to only show after it has fully set to the AJAX response.

Comment: When the success callback occurs, the ajax response has been fully received. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/Product/Index',
    data: {
        slug: this.id,
        type: this.name,
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#quickviewModal").html("");
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $("#quickviewModal").html(response);
        $('#quickviewModal').modal('show');
    },
    complete: function(response) {
    }
});
```

More information about jQuery state, you might find out here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/